# Can I use the same Firebase GoogleService-Info.plist for two iOS apps that have different bundle ids?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

We run internal tests on our company Testflight while in development that never go live but then launch games on the client's Testflight. This results in us having two different bundle ids where the internal bundle id is something like *com.mycompany.client.appname* and the client's is *com.clientcompany.appname*.

Normally we add a second GoogleService-Info.plist since Firebase logs a message about this (which IMO should be a fatal error):

> Project Bundle ID org.icivics.ratify does not match any bundle IDs in your GoogleServices-Info.plist files. This will result in an app that will fail to initialize.

However an app went live recently with only the GoogleService-Info.plist for the internal bundle id. Yet the dashboard appears to be properly reporting metrics despite being in an app with a bundle id that doesn't match the one in GoogleService-Info.plist. Because metrics are still being reported I'm not sure if I should be concerned about this.

**What are the consequences if we don't push an update with the correct GoogleService-Info.plist?**

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleService-Info.plist` file for a project contains the information about all iOS apps in that Firebase project. When you initialize the Firebase app in your code, it looks for the configuration data for the current app based on its bundle ID.

If you use an outdated `GoogleService-Info.plist` in your app, it may not be able to find the information for the app. In that case Firebase will fail to initialize and raise an error.

Comment: "The GoogleService-Info.plist file for a project contains the information about all iOS apps in that Firebase project." This is not true; each app requires its own GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Comment: "If you use an outdated GoogleService-Info.plist in your app, it may not be able to find the information for the app. In that case Firebase will fail to initialize and raise an error." This I am aware of, however as stated in the initial question, the app is tracking metrics normally despite the documentation/errors saying otherwise.

Comment: Interesting. Analytics definitely uses a single key for all apps in a project. But I'd expect it to still require some app-specific information to report events at the application level. Then again: maybe it just send the app ID/bundle ID over to the server, which can then look them up as needed.